# Library to lemmatize German compound verbs

Tags: nlp, spacy, lemmatization

I'm trying to lemmatize a German text using HannoverTagger (same results were achieved with SpaCy).

```
from HanTa import HanoverTagger as ht

tagger = ht.HanoverTagger('morphmodel_ger.pgz')

print(tagger.analyze('Wir geben niemals auf.'))
```

What I get is 'Wir geben niemals auf', but what I would expect is 'Wir aufgeben niemals' or 'Wir aufgeben niemals aufgeben'.

Any ideas what kind of lemmatizer I could use to achieve the desired result?